# Microsoft Web Farm just porked IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-farm

I installed web farm framework 2.1 from web platform installer.  Just fooling around on our dev machine I set up a server farm.

added the name, set it up to provision with a username.
added a server, it couldn't connect, probably need to have the network ops open a port or two.
added the server anyway and hit finish.

Then up comes a popup [image: rewrite rules]

Unfortunately I hit yes. Now I can't undo the damage I did. This dev server can't serve any traffic and is basically just busted.

Where can I undo this rule? I don't see a routing rules page of the server farm, it only shows application, platform provision and workflow builder.

I uninstalled/reinstalled the web farm thing along with ARR and now it shows the routing rules but there are none. Something must be left over from prior? IIS is still not serving a simple html page.

What should I do?

**so we had to uninstall/reinstall the url rewrite module. for some reason it wasn't displaying anymore. after doing that, there was an inbound rule called ARR_myserverfarmname_loadbalance. Disabling that unporked our IIS.**

Comment: Can you do a system restore and restore your server to a previous state?

Comment: I think you might want to re-think your usage of the word "bricked" - "bricked" is used when the device is no more useful than a brick, because it's in a broken, un-recoverable state (often because of a low-level firmware error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the "URL Rewrite" module in the IIS Manager. Pop open `inetmgr`, select your machine, and look for URL Rewrite under the Features View. I'm not 100% sure where Web Farm put this re-write rule, but if it is "all incoming requests" then top-level makes the most sense.